# How to verify chunked response data with REST-assured?

Tags: java, integration-testing, rest-assured, chunked-encoding

I have a Jersey resource that returns `text/csv` as [`ChunkedOutput`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ChunkedOutput.html).

I'm trying to write a test with [REST-assured](http://rest-assured.io/) that should verify correctness of the returned data.

Unfortunately I can't find anything about verifying chunked response data with REST assured in their docs and googling hasn't yielded anything useful.

I can verify status code, response headers, etc. like this:

```
given()
    .spec(mySpec)
    .accept("text/csv")
    .when()
    .post("/mycsvpath")
    .then()
    .statusCode(200);
```

I can see that the response has the `Transfer-Encoding=chunked` header, but how would I verify the actual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. It's actually really simple:

```
Response r = given()
                .spec(mySpec)
                .accept("text/csv")
                .when()
                .post("/mycsvpath")
String data = r.asString();
```